# When OnPrem with Kubernetes, what is the recommended way to do file storage buckets?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, storage, google-cloud-storage

When you are running kubernetes on GKS, AKS, etc, you use your cloud provider specific storage bucket such as Amazon S3, google cloud storage, azure blob storage, to store your raw binary content in a super fast, easy to use manner.

But when you are deploying Kubernetes behind the firewall, you do not have a storage bucket SDK from your cloud provider.

What is the alternative to this when you are using, for example, OpenShift? Do we have to just use persistent volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many, many options. The following all provide an S3-compatible object storage API:

- If you are using OpenShift, you can install [OpenShift Data Foundation](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift-data-foundation), which includes the Noobaa object storage service. This provides `ObjectBucket` and `ObjectBucketClaim` resources that are analgous to `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` resources.
- You could run [MinIO](https://min.io/), which can be deployed on Kubernetes via [an operator](https://github.com/minio/minio-operator/blob/master/README.md) or a helm chart.
- You can run your own Ceph cluster, which includes the [object gateway](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/index.html).
- You could run [OpenStack Swift](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/).